# Desativar Identity Entity Framework temporariamente em tempo de execução

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, identity

Eu preciso sincronizar 2 bancos de dados, Um fica na maquina local e um no servidor, Eu obtenho os dados que preciso por Api via Json, E ele me retorna a model com os dados que preciso inserir.. Porém estes dados já vem com ID e eu precisava manter este id, Só que quando dou o Add pelo Entity framework ele insere e atribui um novo Id aos registros que passei.. 
Exemplo a model a seguir:

```
public class Cliente{
public int Id {get;set;}
public stirng Nome {get;set;}
}
```

Meu Json retorna essa model assim:

```
cliente.Id == 1;
cliente.Nome == "TESTE";
```

Quando eu dou o insert:

```
_ctx.Clientes.Add(cliente);
_ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Ao invés de o EF inserir o registro com o Id 1 que foi o que esta preenchido na model, Ele obedece o **Identity** e atribui outro Id para a model, Ex 2, Porém eu precisa que ficasse o 1.. 
Eu **não** posso desabilitar na model a opção:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

Pois quando eu faço o cadastro pelo sistema normal eu preciso que gere o Id normal, Só quando eu pegar os dados do servidor pela Api, Que preciso que salve com o mesmo ID que vem do Servidor.. Porém não achei uma opção que faça isso, Sem que eu tenha que remover a opção da model

Ja tentei fazer o seguinte:

```
 _ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo].Cliente] OFF");
 _ctx.SaveChanges();
 _ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo].Cliente] ON");
```

Para desativar o Identity antes de eu dar o insert, Porém mesmo assim o Entity atribui outro id aos registros que eu incluo.
Teria alguma forma de desabilitar o Identity sem ter de remover da model a opção: DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity ou informar antes do insert que somente para aquelas registro deve se manter o Id informado? Alguém pode me ajudar

Comment: Tu tens um API no lado do servidor ?

Comment: Tenho, Porem a API faz o trabalho dela corretamente, Ela me devolve os dados preenchidos, Eu preencho a model lado cliente normalmente também, O empasse era manter o ID, mas eu consegui, Vou responder a pergunta com a solução aqui